# Numpy: How to stack a single array into each row of a bigger array and turn it into a 2D array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, stack, concatenation

I have a numpy array named `heartbeats` with 100 rows. Each row has 5 elements.

I also have a single array named `time_index` with 5 elements.
I need to prepend the `time index` to each row of `heartbeats`.

```
heartbeats = np.array([
    [-0.58, -0.57, -0.55, -0.39, -0.40],
    [-0.31, -0.31, -0.32, -0.46, -0.46]
])
time_index = np.array([-2, -1, 0, 1, 2])
```

What I need:

```
array([-2, -0.58],
      [-1, -0.57],
      [0, -0.55],
      [1, -0.39],
      [2, -0.40],
      [-2, -0.31],
      [-1, -0.31],
      [0, -0.32],
      [1, -0.46],
      [2, -0.46])
```

I only wrote two rows of `heartbeats` to illustrate.

Comment: Are you using numpy? Also, what happened to the second row?

Comment: The operation you are looking for is "concatenate" or "stack" in numpy terminology, not "merge"

Comment: "Pair" means "two elements". I think you meant "rows".

Comment: Please add a numpy tag and use `np....` if you are using numpy. Otherwise, please indicate which array package you are using. Python does not support multidimensional arrays in the standard library.

Comment: Thanks for being responsive! It's a nice change from the usual "dump and walk away" approach some new users take.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using numpy, the exact output array you are looking for can be made by stacking a repeated version of `time_index` with the raveled version of `heartbeats`:

```
np.stack((np.tile(time_index, len(heartbeats)), heartbeats.ravel()), axis=-1)
```

Comment: @d.b. `h.shape[0]` is a good alternative, `flatten` is not because it copies the data unnecessarily, while `ravel` does not. It's rare that you want to use `flatten` over `ravel`. Also, doing the transpose will alter the layout of the array in memory over stacking on `axis=-1`.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach, using broadcasting

```
In [13]: heartbeats = np.array([
    ...:     [-0.58, -0.57, -0.55, -0.39, -0.40],
    ...:     [-0.31, -0.31, -0.32, -0.46, -0.46]
    ...: ])
    ...: time_index = np.array([-2, -1, 0, 1, 2])
```

Make a target array:

```
In [14]: res = np.zeros(heartbeats.shape + (2,), heartbeats.dtype)

In [15]: res[:,:,1] = heartbeats     # insert a (2,5) into a (2,5) slot

In [17]: res[:,:,0] = time_index[None]   # insert a (5,) into a (2,5) slot

In [18]: res
Out[18]: 
array([[[-2.  , -0.58],
        [-1.  , -0.57],
        [ 0.  , -0.55],
        [ 1.  , -0.39],
        [ 2.  , -0.4 ]],

       [[-2.  , -0.31],
        [-1.  , -0.31],
        [ 0.  , -0.32],
        [ 1.  , -0.46],
        [ 2.  , -0.46]]])
```

and then reshape to 2d:

```
In [19]: res.reshape(-1,2)
Out[19]: 
array([[-2.  , -0.58],
       [-1.  , -0.57],
       [ 0.  , -0.55],
       [ 1.  , -0.39],
       [ 2.  , -0.4 ],
       [-2.  , -0.31],
       [-1.  , -0.31],
       [ 0.  , -0.32],
       [ 1.  , -0.46],
       [ 2.  , -0.46]])
```

`[17]` takes a (5,), expands it to (1,5), and then to (2,5) for the insert.  Read up on `broadcasting`.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative way, you can repeat `time_index`  by `np.concatenate` based on the specified times:

```
concatenated = np.concatenate([time_index] * heartbeats.shape[0])
# [-2 -1  0  1  2 -2 -1  0  1  2]

# result = np.dstack((concatenated, heartbeats.reshape(-1))).squeeze()
result = np.array([concatenated, heartbeats.reshape(-1)]).T
```

Using `np.concatenate` may be faster than `np.tile`. This solution is faster than *Mad Physicist*, but the fastest is using broadcasting as *hpaulj*'s answer.